# pygame: changing layer of a sprite

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, layer

I am making a program with sprites. I have a "box" where the sprites is going to come inside and show only inside the "box". I have tried to find how to change layers and came to this documentation on [pygame.sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)s, but I can't understand the codes there for changing layers. Does anyone know how I can set the sprite in the middle of the layers instead of on the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the layer of a `Sprite`, simply use the [`change_layer`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates.change_layer) method:

> **change_layer()**
>
> *changes the layer of the sprite*
>
> `change_layer(sprite, new_layer) -> None`

Comment: @Pclover What does your code look like? I would say it should be wherever you are planning on changing the sprite layer